# wxwidgets Bind() term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument in event.h

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am getting the following error and I am lost as to what the error is actually trying to tell me.

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments event.h line 516
```

This is of course the wxwidgets event.h file

the code that is causing the error is the Bind() in this method.

```
int Layout::CreateWindow()
{
    wxPanel * m_pPanel = new wxPanel(this, -1);
    wxBoxSizer * m_pVbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxTextCtrl * m_pReceiveBox = new wxTextCtrl(m_pPanel, wxID_ANY,    wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_MULTILINE | wxTE_READONLY);
    wxTextCtrl * m_pSendBox = new wxTextCtrl(m_pPanel, ID_SEND, wxEmptyString, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER);
    wxStatusBar * m_pStatusBar = new wxStatusBar(m_pPanel, wxID_ANY, wxSTB_DEFAULT_STYLE);

    m_pVbox->Add(m_pReceiveBox, 1, wxEXPAND | wxLEFT | wxRIGHT | wxBOTTOM, 2);
    m_pVbox->Add(m_pSendBox, 0, wxEXPAND | wxLEFT | wxRIGHT, 2);
    m_pVbox->Add(m_pStatusBar, 0, wxEXPAND);

    m_pPanel->SetSizer(m_pVbox);

    Bind(wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER, &Layout::OnSendEnter, ID_SEND);
    return 0;
}

enum ID
{
    ID_SEND             =   wxID_HIGHEST+1,
    ID_MENU_CONNECT,
    ID_MENU_DISCONNECT
};
```

I have a feeling I am using the wrong overloaded function, but if I try and change the Bind() to

```
Bind(wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER, &Layout::OnSendEnter, this, ID_SEND);
```

I get an intellisense error: no instance of overloaded function "Layout::Bind matches the argument list. I am sure it is probably obvious for those more versed, so please explain my misunderstanding

UPDATE: Layout.h

```
class Layout : public wxFrame
{
public:
    // Constructor
    Layout(const wxString & title);

    // Event Methods - ** possibly private ***
    void OnConnect(wxCommandEvent & event);
    void OnDisconnect(wxCommandEvent & event);
    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent & event);
    int OnSendEnter(wxCommandEvent & event);

    // Helper methods - ** possibly private **
    int CreateMenu();
    int CreateWindow();

    // Class members
    wxMenuBar * m_pMenubar;
    wxMenu * m_pFileMenu;
    wxMenu * m_pHelpMenu;
    wxMenu * m_pPortMenu;

};
```

Comment: Your feeling is correct; the second overload is the one to use in this case. What is the declaration of `Layout::OnSendEnter`? It's probably not matching `Bind`'s parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-static member functions, the second overload of `Bind` mentioned in the question is indeed the one to call (the first one is for free functions, static member functions, or function objects).

However, the second parameter of that `Bind` overload is declared like this:

```
void (Class::*method)(EventArg &)
```

(`Class` and `EventArg` are template parameters).

Note the `void` - that's what doesn't match in your case, as your member function is declared to return an `int`.

---

As a side note, you can `Bind` directly to the widget you're interested in, like this:

```
m_pSendBox->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER, &Layout::OnSendEnter, this);
```

Saves you from having to define a custom ID, if event handling was the only reason for having `ID_SEND`.

Comment: of course it is and that had me wondering. As I was editing my original post I questioned whether it should be void. Thanks, sometimes one just needs to step back and take a closer look. Still quite new at this so I am always willing to learn.